# How to compare arrays within nested JSON arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following data in an array:

```
 [{
  Credits: '4',
  Name: 'Computer Science 250: Introduction to Website Design',
  Classes: 
   [ 
      { Day: 'Mon',
       EndTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 18:00:00\'}',
       StartTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 16:30:00\'}' },
      { Day: 'Wed',
       EndTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 18:00:00\'}',
       StartTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 16:30:00\'}' },
      { Day: 'Fri',
       EndTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 18:00:00\'}',
       StartTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 16:30:00\'}' } ] }

  {
  Credits: '3',
  Name: 'Math 220: Differential Equations',
  Classes: 
   [ 
      { Day: 'Mon',
       EndTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 18:30:00\'}',
       StartTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 17:30:00\'}' },
     { Day: 'Wed',
      EndTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 18:30:00\'}',
      StartTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 17:30:00\'}' },
     { Day: 'Fri',
      EndTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 18:30:00\'}',
      StartTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 17:30:00\'}' } ] }]
```

Problem is I have to sort the data by the EndTime (only this part of data is ordered the rest is not) how can I do this?

Or how can I atleast sort the data based on the properties of the inner array?

I'm working with javascript.

**EDIT**

The problem is to find whether the subjects provided in the json array will clash or not based on the start and ending times, for example the subjects above occur at the same time so therefore they clash.

Comment: That JSON is invalid (or you don't have any JSON and your JavaScript variable declaration is incomplete)

Comment: Break down the problem into smaller pieces. This library may help: http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: Please provide the expected output for the sample data you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the inner arrays, extend their elements with the course name (or all the course information), and concatenate them together, to finally sort them with a custom compare function:

```js
function byDayTime(schedule) {
    const weekDays = {Mon:1, Tue:2, Wed:3, Thu:4, Fri:5};
    return schedule.reduce( (acc, course) => 
        acc.concat(course.Classes.map( cls => 
            Object.assign({}, cls, { courseName: course.Name })
        ))
    , [] ).sort( (a, b) => 
        weekDays[a.Day] - weekDays[b.Day] || a.EndTime - b.EndTime 
    );
}

// Sample data
const schedule = [{
    Credits: '4',
    Name: 'Computer Science 250: Introduction to Website Design',
    Classes: [{
        Day: 'Mon',
        EndTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 18:00:00\'}',
        StartTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 16:30:00\'}'
    }, { Day: 'Wed',
        EndTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 18:00:00\'}',
        StartTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 16:30:00\'}'
    }, { Day: 'Fri',
        EndTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 18:00:00\'}',
        StartTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 16:30:00\'}'
    }] 
}, {
    Credits: '3',
    Name: 'Math 220: Differential Equations',
    Classes: [{ 
        Day: 'Mon',
        EndTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 18:30:00\'}',
        StartTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 17:30:00\'}'
    }, { 
        Day: 'Wed',
        EndTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 18:30:00\'}',
        StartTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 17:30:00\'}'
    }, { 
        Day: 'Fri',
        EndTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 18:30:00\'}',
        StartTime: '{ts \'1970-01-01 17:30:00\'}'
    }] 
}];

// Get array ordered by day/time:
const result = byDayTime(schedule);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Begin your work by parse your Json (with JSON.parse for example :p )

When you'll have your javascript array, you'll can use the sort function very simply (if your able to parse your date to).

For example, here I sort an array, by TYPE (PHYSIQUE before others) and alphabetically:

```
return $.map(caracInfos, function (caracInfo) {
        return new CaracInfo(caracInfo);
    }).sort(function (caracInfo1, caracInfo2) {
        if (caracInfo1.type === caracInfo2.type) return caracInfo1.carac.localeCompare(caracInfo2.carac);
        if (caracInfo1.type === CaracInfo.TYPES["PHYSIQUE"]) return -1;
        if (caracInfo2.type === CaracInfo.TYPES["PHYSIQUE"]) return 1;
        return 0;
    });
```